# Azure event hub error when debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have created a azure function with event hub trigger and keep getting this error "The listener for function 'Transfers.OrdersFunction was unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)." when I run debugger. I've followed this code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp and I am using Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this problem is related to your dev machine firewall blocking ports 5671 and 5672. Check this out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide

If you can’t open those tpc ports, there is a trick for that. Add this to the end of your connection string: **TransportType=AmqpWebSockets**

But could be how you added the connection string to the code. You must make sure you get the connection string for a specific event hub in a namespace:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string#connection-string-for-a-specific-event-hub-in-a-namespace

When you apply that to the code, make sure you remove the "EntityPath=" part.

For example , consider the connections string is :

"Endpoint=sb://myhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=mypolicy;SharedAccessKey=bc34534534543l+4wyWi5jbrQ=;EntityPath=myhub;"

remove the entity path and add it to the "local.settings.json" as you connection string setting

```
 {
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "MyConnSetting": "Endpoint=sb://myhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=mypolicy;SharedAccessKey=bc34534534543l+4wyWi5jbrQ=;TransportType=AmqpWebSockets"
  }
}
```

than add the connection string setting and entity path value like this:

```
[Function("Function1")]
    public void Run([EventHubTrigger("myhub", Connection = "MyConnSetting")] string[] input)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"First Event Hubs triggered message: {input[0]}");
    }
```

Remember this is  just a way to force the trigger to use websockets. once you deploy you can set it to use AMQP.
Hope this help!

Comment: Depending on the version of the extensions package used, appending to the connection string will NOT work.   Starting in v5, the bindings use the Azure.Messaging.EventHubs package, which does not allow keys in the connection string not set by the Azure portal.   To specify the websocket transport, you'd do so in the `host.json` settings using the "transportType` key as discussed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings

Comment: Also worth noting, whether you're using TCP or WebSockets, the protocol is always AMQP - it's just a different path for establishing the connection.